# Html > shopping cart button 

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am wondering what should I properly use for an HTML table that has an add to cart buttons and buy all button.

So, Should I use

`<input class="btn" type="button" value="Buy -Shopping cart"/>` or can I use

`<a href="#" title="Buy Shopping card"><b>&#43;</b><img width="16" height="10" alt="Cart" src="images/cart.png"></a>`

Also, I would need to *enable* and *disable* those buttons using *JavaScript*

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that both of your initial suggestions would be fine, it's more a matter of how you'd like your buttons to be styled. If you use the `<input type='button'>` method, it'll be a bit harder to use CSS to customize your buttons. Links, on the other hand, are easier to style. So, if you need custom-looking buttons, go with the `<a href="#" title="Buy Shopping card"><b>&#43;</b><img width="16" height="10" alt="Cart" src="images/cart.png"></a>` version.

Answer (score 2):

That purely depends on what your shopping cart's code looks like. In general, I'd say people use buttons for internal shopping carts (that are a part of a POST form) - and input type image can be used as well for those - and links for external shopping carts (like PayPal).

To enable/disable with javascript, you could have it dynamically insert "disabled=true" for the button or take out the link and replace it with "#" for the link. But again, depends on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use an a-tag for this unless you want search engine spiders to come and click on all your add to cart and buy button -links. Think about it :)

No but seriously, a-tags is for linking pages together, and `<input type="submit">` or `<button>` tags are for actions that changes states. Adding an item to a cart or buying something is an action that changes a state.